# Getting back Java 6

Tags: java, osx-mountain-lion

Apple released an update about Java and now I can't start my Cassandra db anymore. I think I will need Java 6 to use it but I can't uninstall Java 7 because I need it to run eclipse v.4 ... Does anyone know how to get back the Java Preference panel where I can choose which version I want to use?

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002155/apples-most-recent-java-update-removes-java-preferences-how-to-change-from-she/13003261#13003261 for some more info. There are still issues with the method as we're still feeling our way through the problem

Answer (score 0):

To find the Java Control Panel on `Mac OS X` (10.7.3 and above), under `System Preferences` click on the `Java` icon to access the `Java Control Panel`

[EDIT] try running `Java Preferences.app` under `Applications/Utilities`

Comment: but i only show 1.7 in my java runtime environment, i've installed java 2012 -006 from apple but i can't find where it is :(

Answer (score 0):

Try setting JAVA_HOME manually to the location of the previous version.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```